# A Bash script to check if a string is present in a comma separated list of strings

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to know a neat way in which I can check to see if a string is there in a comma separated value of strings. eg:
if

```
x="abc,def,ghi"
y="abc"
```

it should return true

and 
if

```
y="ab"
```

then it should return false

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use globs:

```
[[ ",$x," = *",$y,"* ]]
```

Comment: That's a clever alternative to regex matching in this case.

Comment: You could also normalize the string this way (add commas at the beginning and end) and use regex matching `[[ ",$x," =~ ",$y," ]]` -- that is even one more character shorter.

Comment: Good point - it is the normalization of the list that enables the simplicity of your answer(s).

Comment: any way we can handle spaces present before or after commas in this situation? like 'abc' should also match 'abc ,'

Comment: @PetrSkocik Would be better if you could explain your command here

Answer (score 6):

Use bash's [regular-expression-matching operator, `=~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
[[ $x =~ (^|,)"$y"(,|$) ]]
```

*Caveat*: While the above regex happens to be portable, the particular flavor of regular expressions supported by `=~` is *platform-dependent* due to use of a given platform's regex libraries.

Case in point: [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) suggests use of `\b` to match word boundaries, which works on Linux, but not OSX, for instance. The closest thing to `\b` in POSIX are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, but, unfortunately, these don't work on Linux.